# Create total calculation of multiple span elements

Tags: jquery, field, calculator

I am trying to create a calculator that takes the value of an input field (quantity) that is then used in a formula and output into a span element (cubics). This is all working. Please see my jsfiddle.

Example code

```
<input id="07flute" type="text" value="0" />
<span id="cubics"></span>

$("#07flute").keyup(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val / 50 * 0.0113 : "Invalid number");
    $("#cubics").text(val);
});
```

I would now like to add calculations that total the Quantity and Cubics within that table, though i'm not sure how to calculate these from span elements. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

updated http://jsfiddle.net/weedy/vcD9A/

Edited answer

```
function total() {
var total = 0;
$('span.cubics').each(function() {
    var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
    total += isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
});
$('.totalcubics').text(total.toFixed(2));
}

$('input.qty').keyup(function() {
var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
val = (val ? val / 50 * $(this).data('cubics') : '');
$(this).closest('td').next().find('span.cubics').text(val);
total();
});

var $form = $('#my-form'),
$summands = $form.find('input'),
$sumDisplay = $('span#totalquantity');

$form.keyup(function()
{
var sum = 0;
$summands.each(function ()
{
    var value = Number($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
});

$sumDisplay.text(sum);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/weedy/zn9kv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are biding multiple `keyup` handlers I suggest using a helper function:

```
function total() {
    $('.totalcubics').html(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('table').find('span').not(this).each(function () {
            var n = parseFloat($(this).text());
            total += isNaN(n) ? 0 : n;
        });
        return total;
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nJW7u/

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Is this something similar if i want to calculate a total for the quantity spans too?

Comment: @LouisaTracey You are welcome, yes, you can use classes instead of IDs, `$('.inputs').keyup()`, then you can query the DOM and select the target span element individually using `this` keyword.

Comment: Could you do jsfiddle for an example? Sorry, i am quite a novice.

Answer (score 1):

Check this doSum function:

```
function doSum(){
    var one = parseFloat($("#cubics").text(),10);
    if(isNaN(one)) one = 0; 
    var two = parseFloat($("#cubics2").text(),10);
    if(isNaN(two)) two = 0; 
    var three = parseFloat($("#cubics3").text(),10);    
    if(isNaN(three)) three = 0;     
    $('.totalcubics').text(one+two+three); 
}
$("#07flute").keyup(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val / 50 * 0.0113 : "Invalid number");
    $("table #cubics").text(val);
    doSum();
});

$("#08flute").keyup(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val / 50 * 0.0128 : "Invalid number");
    $("#cubics2").text(val);
    doSum();
});

$("#09flute").keyup(function () {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    val = (val ? val / 50 * 0.0128 : "Invalid number");
    $("#cubics3").text(val);
    doSum();
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/UHfR8/

Comment: The result is nan until you have all values.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore's `reduce` method would be perfect. http://underscorejs.org/#reduce